# KVM. kvm-ok not found error

Tags: docker, kvm-virtualization

Ubuntu 22.04

I'm trying to set up KVM by following this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation and unfortunately Im getting the following error when I run kvm-ok

```
Command 'kvm-ok' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install cpu-checker
```

I then tried to install cpu-checker and it gave this error

```
cpu-checker : Depends: msr-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Ive enabled Virtualization in the BIOS (AMD Ryzen7 GFX CPU) and Ive tried the --fix-broken install.

kvm is a requirement to install Docker Desktop which is what Im trying to get working,
Does anyone know how to fix this so I can get kvm/Docker working?

**Installed Repositories**
Its suggested that this problem is being caused by having conflicting repositories, but how do you find out which one is the culprit? I have a few repositories installed for Audio Apps (kxstudio), Brave Browser, Wine, Proton, VSCode and Chrome. They were all installed in the last few months. (The system was re-built 3 months ago)

```
sudo grep -rhE ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list* 
  
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu/ jammy main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/plugins/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/apps/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu bionic main
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu focal main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/plugins/ubuntu focal main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/apps/ubuntu focal main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu focal main
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
deb [arch="all", signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/protonvpn-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable main
```

Thanks
Jef

Comment: You should add information requested to your original posting.  Do you have any PPA's in addition to the original ones? What do you have checked in Software & Updates/Ubuntu Software? Something is preventing getting the dependencies for the qemu-system-x86 package.

Comment: Thanks ubfan, I added a list of repositories that I have installed, but how do you find out if one may be causing the problem?

Comment: focal...bionic...jammy  What a mess.  First, get rid of the old ones, then see what problems remain.

Comment: yes its very embarrasing to have repositories from different versions of Ubuntu, but thats kxstudio, so not much I can do. Lots of vst's and audio apps and plugins use it so thats just how they roll. Anyway, I removed their repositories for the moment and unfortunately I still get the same dependencies error when I try to install qemu-system-x86.

Comment: After you removed the old repos, did you run sudo apt update before trying the install?

Comment: Thanks, I tracked down the culprit. It was an Audio package that had an unmet dependency and purging it from the system has let me install the qemu package. Why it would have caused a problem for installing qemu, I have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kvm is a part of the package qemu-system-x86 these days.  Install that package.

```
sudo apt install qemu-system-x86
```

Create an image with (fill in your own names):

```
kvm -m 4096 -cdrom ${PWD}/$ISO -boot d ${NAME}
```

and run the image with (adjust cores/memory as needed):

```
kvm -smp cores=4,threads=2 -cpu host -m 4096 -vga virtio -usb $IMAGE
```

Comment: Hi, I tried running sudo apt install qemu-system-x86
but it gave me around 15 unmet dependency errors.  
```
 qemu-system-x86 : Depends: libfdt1 (>= 1.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
...

                   Depends: ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms but it is not going to be installed
 ...
                   Recommends: qemu-block-extra (= 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.15) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: cpu-checker but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

``

Comment: Sorry, that comment all ran together as one line, It says these are Unmet Dependencies
```
libfdt1,  
libibverbs1,  
libpmem1,  
librdmacm1,  
libslirp0,  
qemu-system-common,  
qemu-system-data,  
seabios,  
ipxe-qemu,  
ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms,  
qemu-system-gui,  
qemu-utils,  
ovmf,  
qemu-block-extra,  
cpu-checker,  
```

Comment: @Artillery have you run `sudo apt update` recently?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I did an update just there, but unfortunately still getting same errors

Answer (score 0):

The conflict seems to have been caused by a package called avldrums.lv2 which had an unmet dependency avldrums.lv2-data. I think this package was installed along with a suit of Audio packages and VST's by Ubuntu Studio, (but not 100% sure). I have no idea why that would have had a knock on effect with installing other unrelated packages, but purging it from the system has worked and I can now install qemu-system-x86 and I can run the command kvm-ok and proceed with installing Docker. Thanks to all who helped. :)